# Is adding JavaScript object in custom data expensive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I add custom data to my html controls, how will the performance and memory consumption be in the following scenario:
1. Adding a string or a number in customdata.
2. Adding an existing object (already created object in previous lines of code).
3. Adding a map (object) of (string, existingObject).

By existingObject, I mean an already created object, eg: map/object created in previous lines of code, or model object in angular js.

As per my understanding, storing object as custom data is like storing reference of an object which is already there, so it should not be expensive in terms of space, nor should it make html page heavy. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "expensive"?

Comment: By expensive I mean, bad in terms of space and performance

Comment: "bad in terms of space and performance" that's pretty relative. If I'm writing a one off job, if it takes 2 hours to run vs 1 hour, I may not care. If I'm writing a web page and my code locks up someone's browser all the time, I probably care. "Bad" is something you have to define for your project.  And the easiest way it to just try it.  If you see a problem (either through usage observation, profiling, etc.) then you can determine if it is worth fixing. No one can say without knowing exactly what you are doing (ie seeing your code, knowing your target browsers, etc.) if it will be a problem.